# Replace a string in all Vcorpus content - R

Tags: r, tm

I have a large Vcorpus "wc" with 200 elements, each element wc[i] contain an article content and a list of its metadata .

```
> lapply(wci[1], as.character)
 $ 1
 [1] "En guise de mise en bouche\n laissez-vous porter par cette mignardise musicale!\n \n ...etc "
```

I want to delete "/n" from the content and make it look like this

```
[1] "En guise de mise en bouche laissez-vous porter par cette mignardise musicale! ...etc "
```

and of course repeat the same operation for all Vcorus content (200 elements)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use `gsub` in-order to do a global replacement.

```
x <- "En guise de mise en bouche\n laissez-vous porter par cette mignardise musicale!\n \n ...etc "
gsub("\\n", "", x)
# [1] "En guise de mise en bouche laissez-vous porter par cette mignardise musicale!  ...etc "
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it ,

```
wc<-tm_map(wc, content_transformer( function(x) gsub("\\n", "", x)))
```

content_transformer :  functions which modify the content of an
R corpus.
tm-map : for an interface to apply transformations to corpora elements.
gsub : replace a string .